# How to get class model by name from an object?

Tags: c#, object

i have two class model ( customers & orders )

```
  public class customer
  {

    private string _cid;
    public string cid
    {
        get { return _cid; }
        set { _cid = value; }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    private string _Tel;
    public string Tel
    {
        get { return _Tel; }
        set { _Tel = value; }
    }

  }
  // ===============================
  public class order
  {

    private string _oid;
    public string oid
    {
        get { return _oid; }
        set { _oid = value; }
    }

    private string _date;
    public string date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set { _date = value; }
    }

    private customer _cust = new customer();
    public customer cust
    {
        get { return _cust; }
        set { _cust = value; }
    }

  }
```

i make from this two class models a relational object
like the following

```
        order obj = new order
        {
            oid = "1",
            date = "12/12/2014",
            cust.cid = "1",
            cust.name = "mohamed",
            cust.Tel = "00201143683774"
        };
```

now i have an object has many class models and it's name is obj . 
the question is 
what is the shortest way to filter it like the following.

```
  public object filterobj(object objname,string modelname)
  {
  // ??? how filter object and return class model by his name properties collection 
  }

 filterobj(obj , "order");    //  return order class model properties collection (oid & date)
 // or 
 filterobj(obj , "customer"); //  return customer class model properties collection (cid , name & Tel)
```

Comment: What problem you're trying to solve with this? Appears to be [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for me.

Comment: i want a code in filterobject() that get object and return model that is was i appointed it by name

Comment: I think this is a question about [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a good approach to your problem. I think you're confusing relational database concept with OOP.

First of all, you should not initialize `_cust` directly. Do it via the property. After all, you need a valid input for field `_cust`, right? (i.e. a `customer` object has already been instantiated).

Second, why would you need to filter it? You can retrieve a `customer` object from an `order` object with property `cust`. Looking at your `filterobj` function, it returns an object. You still need to check if it's returning an object of the correct type (`customer` or `order`).

So, to sum it up, here's my answer:

1. delete the initialization part of field `_cust`
2. when you want to retrieve the customer of an order, use the property `cust`.
3. similarly, *if* you want to retrieve the order of a consumer, use the property `order`. But I see this isn't the case.

I hope it helps. I'm new here.